# Center input inside div

Tags: css

I understand this is simple, but I cannot make it work

I have an input and a button inside a div and I cannot centralize the input anymore. I was using display: flex and it was great, but I had to change it to display: none so I could toggle this div with other element.

I tried margin: 0 auto; text-align, positioning, but I can't keep input at div center without flexbox. What works is setting parent's div height and then input's height 100%, but this messes up the button

```css
  
#input-container {
  /* position: relative; */
  background: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  /* padding: 5px; */
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

#input-container input {
        background-color: black;
  /* 
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto; */
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="input-container" class="togglable" style="display: none;">
  <input type="text" name="search" onkeyup="search(event);">

  <button onClick="toggleMe()">
                    <span id="icon-close" class="fa fa-times"></span>
                </button>
</div>
```

[image]

WHAT I NEED:

[image: S.]

Comment: Please add a [**Minimal**, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Made a snippet out of your code, would you mind checking the code you shared is correct?

Comment: Any reason why not flexbox ?

Comment: I was using flexbox, but I needed to set display to none so I could hide the div for a toggle function. This is the code...

Comment: @tramada in that case you have lot more to code, you have play around on `js` and handle the style property using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can start doing something like this, using `flex`:

```css
#input-container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  background: #390034;
  width: 300px;
}

.txtSearch {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="input-container" class="togglable">

  <input type="text" name="search" class="txtSearch" onkeyup="search(event);">

  <button onClick="toggleMe()">
                <span id="icon-close" class="fa fa-times">X</span>
            </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just saw his ping LOL, commented as well, may be not the right choice, I agree... if he thinks this doesn't work then happy to take the answer out :)

Comment: Your answer is good. But I just thought to let you know in case you missed it. I prefer flex as well and would have answered the same way.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I was using flex, but I needed to change it to display: none, thats what started the problem

Comment: @AlwaysHelping nope, I saw OP comment after posting the answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @tramada, `flex` plays really good for layout designs and for your question it fits correctly now coming to your question regarding solve the `display:none;` property you have to look into `js` and would be happy to spend some more time to fix the issue if you say what exactly the issue on using `flex`.